# What does "sect." mean?

Tags: terminology

For example, [Centaurea sect. Microlophus](https://www.biotaxa.org/Phytotaxa/article/view/phytotaxa.480.2.2)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_(botany)), a taxonomic level. In plants it's a possible level between genus and species.

See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_(biology) as the term is used differently in zoology.

Comment: So in my example above Microlophus is a Section? And is this different from Genus - Species - Subspecies?

Comment: @AlLelopath Yes. It's different because Microlophus is a group of species within a genus. If you have subspecies, those are within a species. All of the levels are quite arbitrary, but are used to avoid having to rename things every time you discover or want to emphasize some particular aspect of taxonomy.